# facebook js sdk. How do I login with facebook, without the user actually login into facebook?

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I am new to stackoverflow, so I hope that I ask the question correctly.

For a website that I am working on, I have to implement login in using your facebook account. I have this working for the biggest part, since the user is able to login with using facebook and I'm able to retrieve the information I want.

But the problem is, whenever the user logs in with their facebook account, he automatically gets logged in into facebook itself. And whenever the user presses the log out button, facebook logs him out too. For the facebook login, I am using the javascript sdk from facebook.

This can be quit anoying for the user, since it must be possible for a random user to login my website using their facebook account, even when someone else is logged into facebook itself on the same computer.

So my question is: is it possible to login with facebook, without the user actually login into facebook, like just let facebook verify the account and send the requested information back? Using the facebook js sdk off course.

Comment: Just to be clear, what I am trying to do, is to make the facebook login on my site, independend from the active user on facebook itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible. You cannot have 2 different Facebook sessions in one browser and you need to login to Facebook in order to login to your App.

Comment: Too bad, thanks for answering anyway. Saved me an enormous amount of searching for an answer, since I couldn't find it in the docs.